# Rails 4 - includes has_many with argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many

Here's my structure:

- A Group has_many Users.
- A User has_many Tasks.
- A task has a due_date.

I want to display One Group, including Users, with their respective Tasks, filtered by due_date.

So my query goes like:

```
group.includes(:users => :tasks)
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
group.includes(:users => :tasks(min, max))
```

Where min and max are the interval for due_date. But passing arguments inside the includes does not work. It throws me a syntax error.
I found some stuff about the lambda condition, but I can't tell whether this is a Rails 3 or Rails 4 feature. It's basically pretty badly documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did in the end:

```
time_range = Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week
group.includes(:users => :tasks).where(tasks: { due_date: time_range })
```

Pretty simple, but works.